# Rails rescue/continue loop after each block NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, loops, rescue

I'm retrieving some API information in the following fashion

```
fetch_api.each do |api|
  save_api = Record.new(name: api.name, height: api.height)
  save_api.save! 
end
```

Most records get saved, no problem. But it seems some are missing height and some name. This causes NoMethodError with undefined method "height" or "name" for nil:NilClass, breaking the loop.

I don't mind if a single record doesn't have its value. How can I continue the loop after this?

I tried

```
if !save_api.save
  next
end
```

with no effect. (**Edit:** Also tried to save without "!"). Each block doesn't seem to accept `rescue`. What else is there?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch_api.each do |api|
  if api.name && api.height
    save_api = Record.new(name: api.name, height: api.height)
  elsif api.name
    save_api = Record.new(name: api.name)
  elsif
    save_api = Record.new(height: api.height)
  end 
    save_api.save! 
end
```

im sure there is a more eloquent way to do it but I think this would work.  you could also use a case statement which would be better but I don't feel like rewriting it all as such.

Answer (score 0):

you can do so

```
Record.new do |record|
   if (record.respond_to?(:name) && record.respond_to?(:height)) 
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple do this:

```
fetch_api.each do |api|
  save_api = Record.new(name: api && api.name, height: api && api.height)
  save_api.save
end
```